# Alternatives to class-level variables for class_eval?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, variables, scope

I have a question about best practices for Ruby variable-scope using `class_eval`.

In this code, in the `class_eval` block, the local variables first and second are undefined.

```
def parent_method(opts={})
first = opts[:percent]
second = (10 * first).to_i

SecondClass.class_eval do 
  def second_method; return {:a => first, :b => second}; end; 
end   
end
```

This appears to be a scoping issue, because the only way I've found to get this to work is to make first and second class-level variables:

```
def parent_method(opts={})
@@first = opts[:percent]
@@second = (10 * @@first).to_i

SecondClass.class_eval do 
  def second_method; return {:a => @@first, :b => @@second}; end; 
end   
end
```

1. What is the best practice for this scenario?  I realize globals are a poor choice for this scenario, because of the wide scope that results, however, are class-level variables similarly frowned upon?
2. Aside from dealing with variable scope, are there any other ways to address the accessibility of these variables from within `class_eval`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is not because of `class_eval`, but because of `def`. When you define a method that way, it introduces a new scope. Here is the best way to fix it:

```
def parent_method(opts={})
    first = opts[:percent]
    second = (10 * first).to_i

    SecondClass.class_eval do 
      define_method(:second_method) { return {:a => first, :b => second} }
    end     
end
```